# Como crear una conexión VPN en c#?

Tags: c#, vpn

Antes de nada me gustaría decir que mi intención es crear un programa que cambie de ip pública cada equis tiempo. Para ello necesito crear una VPN, verdad?
Estoy un poco perdido con este tema.
Para que funcione el VPN tengo que crear una VPN en el centro de redes y recursos compartidos de windows?

1º Me he descargado la aplicación  "DotRas SDKs" del siguiente enlace http://dotras.codeplex.com/ y la he instalado.
Actualmente está instalado en C:\Windows\System32\rasdial.exe

2º He añadido la libreria "DotRas" al proyecto.

3º He ido a la siguiente página http://www.bestvpnusa.com/ y he copiado el Server hostname, el username y el password del VPN que muestra dicha página.

4º he probado los siguientes códigos para conectarme a la VPN, pero sin llegar a ningún éxito.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\rasdial.exe", "bestvpnusa.com bestvpnusa.com 1094");

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "bestvpnusa.com bestvpnusa.com 1094");
```

Solo he conseguido que me devuelva un error 623.

Alguien me podría mostrar un pequeño ejemplo de como se haría, o en su defecto decirme que es en lo que estoy fallando?

Me he bajado un codigo de https://github.com/kimipanda/VPN
pero al ejecutarlo... en la clase VPN.cs 
me da como obsoleto las siguientes lineas de código:

```
    AllUsersPhoneBook.Open();
RasDevice.GetDeviceByName("(PPTP)", RasDeviceType.Vpn));
RasConnection connection = RasConnection.GetActiveConnectionByHandle(this.handle);
```

Gracias por vuestras futuras respuestas y un saludo.

Comment: Una simple búsqueda da información sobre el [error 623](http://www.ordenador.online/Problema/Solucionar-problemas-de-errores-de-la-computadora/C%C3%B3mo-arreglar-un-aviso-de-error-623-.html) De todas maneras no parece un error de programación, si no de uso de la herramienta `rasdial.exe`

Comment: No está muy claro tras tu ultima edición lo que necesitas. Para cambiar tu ip pública hay varias opciones. Si tu conexión no tiene contratada una ip fija, un simple reseteo del router cambiaría probablemente la ip publica. Otra opción como dices es usar una vpn, pero con un servicio gratuito creo que será complicado que puedas elegir mas de una ip, con lo cual no se si te servirá para el problema que quieres resolver (sea el que sea)

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Necesito cambiar de ip, pero sin reiniciar el router.  Como has indicado hay servicios gratuitos por donde puedo conectarme a una VPN por lo que me podría conectarme a más de uno cada equis tiempo y con eso solucionaría lo de la ip publica, no?  Estoy haciendo un programa de scraping pero me bloquean por la ip cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: Yo no he intentado conectar a una vpn nunca desde código. [Aqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/ar-SA/4a49aa78-04a3-4fc0-ae6d-421621292617/problem-to-connect-to-vpn-through-csharp?forum=csharpgeneral) parece que tienes un ejemplo

Comment: Justo ese código ese código aparece en la mitad de mi pregunta y tampoco fui capaz. Solo añades el archivo Dotras.dll a tu proyecto?